# How do I define instance abilities in cancan without defining class abilities?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cancan

How do I define instance abilities in cancan without defining class abilities?

I want to allow the `:manage` action for particular `Course` instances, **not the `Course` class**.

```
# ability.rb
can :manage, Course do |course|
  # Check if the user is a helper for this course
  CourseRole.get_role(user, course) == "helper"
end
```

This works fine for instance variables:

```
# some_view.rb
can? :manage, @course # checks the instance to see if :manage is allowed
```

But if I do this:

```
# some_view.rb
can? :manage, Course
```

it always returns true, which is bad.

Some context:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :course_roles
  has_many :courses, :through => :course_roles
  ...
class CourseRoles < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :course
  ...
class Courses < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :course_roles
  has_many :users, :through => :course_roles
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

instead of `can? :manage, Course`, you can use `can? :manage, Course.new` and be sure that new course objects fail the block you passed in ability.rb